# Showing Msi UI during repair and remove

Tags: wix, burn

I have a custom BA where the MsiPackage is as follows:

```
<Chain>
   ...
   <MsiPackage ... DisplayInternalUI='no' />
</Chain>
```

When the Msi is installed however I would like to show the default UI of the Msi which supports repair and remove.

**How do I show the Msi UI when it is installed?**

UPDATE:
I tried executing the Repair or Uninstall command in the Run method of the custom BA but this does not show the Msi UI

Answer (score 1):

I get the path to the WixBundleOriginalSource in the beginning and instead of showing the custom BA UI, I call the Msi package if the Msipackage is already installed